# SQL/Windows Server compatible with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, sdl-tridion

Is SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 version certified to work in a Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2016 environment?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 Product Prerequisites PDF document](http://sdl.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/file/635543147322472445EY.pdf) that's available from the [Product prerequisites](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B9941B8E-82DD-4551-92BB-F883DEC54EB2) page in the Tridion 2013 SP1 documentation, **neither Windows Server 2016 nor SQL Server 2016 are listed as supported**.

However, that does not mean that the definitely won't work! If you have the software and some time then you could try it (and report back).

Obviously SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is no longer supported by SDL, so the OS and database versions that you use wouldn't affect your support of the installation anyway.

Comment: I remember some of our installers doing checks for the OS and DB version, so you may not be able to install it without some installer trickery.